# Updating a tool-related tag to match the tool's name - markduplicate -> markduplicates

Tags: feature-request, tags

I had a question related to Picard's MarkDuplicates tool, and wanted to tag the question accordingly. There is an existing tag, called "markduplicate" but the tool's name is spelled differently.

https://software.broadinstitute.org/gatk/documentation/tooldocs/4.0.4.0/picard_sam_markduplicates_MarkDuplicates.php

Can we change this tag to the plural?  MarkDuplicates or markduplicates.

Answer (score 1):

I agree the current spelling is clearly wrong and should be fixed, either by editing the tag or if that's not possible, making a new tag to replace it.